# is there any possible way to scan a datagridview fast

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub timeScan_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timeScan.Tick
    If Pre_Initialize() = True Then

        If Trim(txtBarcode.Text) <> Nothing Then
            If frmReceiving.chkDirectSell.Checked = False Then
                Dim chkitem As Boolean = False
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows
                    If row.Cells(1).Value.ToString = txtBarcode.Text Then
                        chkitem = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    i += 1
                Next

                If chkitem = True Then
                    If frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value >= frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value + txtQty.Value Then
                        frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value += 1 * txtQty.Value
                        frmReceiving.grdItem.ClearSelection()
                        frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows(i).Selected = True
                        frmReceiving.grdItem.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i
                        lblMsg.Text = txtQty.Value & " item added."
                        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.SeaGreen
                        chk = Item_Chk(0, txtBarcode.Text)
                        If chk = True Then
                            lblDesc.Text = Item_Get(9, txtBarcode.Text)
                        Else
                            lblDesc.Text = Item_Get(13, txtBarcode.Text)
                        End If
                        txtBarcode.SelectAll()
                    Else
                        lblMsg.Text = "Item are not added. Check the delivered quantity. " & "Barcode: " & txtBarcode.Text
                        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Brown
                        chk = Item_Chk(0, txtBarcode.Text)
                        If chk = True Then
                            lblDesc.Text = Item_Get(9, txtBarcode.Text)
                        Else
                            lblDesc.Text = Item_Get(13, txtBarcode.Text)
                        End If
                        txtBarcode.SelectAll()
                    End If
                Else
                    lblMsg.Text = "Items are not in purchase order. " & "Barcode: " & txtBarcode.Text
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Brown
                    lblDesc.Text = Nothing
                    txtBarcode.SelectAll()
                End If
            ElseIf frmReceiving.chkDirectSell.Checked = True Then
                Dim chk As Boolean = Item_Chk(0, txtBarcode.Text)
                Dim chkcase As Boolean = Item_Chk(1, txtBarcode.Text)
                If chk = False Then
                    If chkcase = False Then
                        lblMsg.Text = "Invalid item."
                        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Brown
                        txtBarcode.SelectAll()
                        lblDesc.Text = Nothing
                        timeScan.Stop()
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
                Dim barcode As String = txtBarcode.Text
                If chkcase = True Then
                    barcode = Item_Get(19, txtBarcode.Text)
                End If
                Dim chkitem As Boolean = False
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows
                    If row.Cells(1).Value.ToString = barcode Then
                        chkitem = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    i += 1
                Next
                If chkitem = True Then
                    If chkcase = True Then
                        frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value += 1 * (txtQty.Value * Item_Get(12, barcode))
                    Else
                        frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value += 1 * txtQty.Value
                    End If
                    frmReceiving.grdItem.ClearSelection()
                    frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows(i).Selected = True
                    frmReceiving.grdItem.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i
                    lblMsg.Text = txtQty.Value & " item/s added."
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.SeaGreen
                    chk = Item_Chk(0, barcode)
                    If chk = True Then
                        lblDesc.Text = Item_Get(9, barcode)
                    Else
                        lblDesc.Text = Item_Get(13, barcode)
                    End If
                    txtBarcode.SelectAll()
                    'lblMsg.Text = "Item is already added."
                    'lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Brown
                    'txtBarcode.SelectAll()
                Else
                    Dim col(5)
                    col(0) = Item_Get(20, barcode)
                    col(1) = barcode
                    col(2) = Item_Get(9, col(1))
                    col(3) = Item_Get(10, col(1))
                    col(4) = "-"
                    If chkcase = True Then
                        col(5) = txtQty.Value * Item_Get(12, barcode)
                    Else
                        col(5) = txtQty.Value
                    End If
                    frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows.Insert(0, col)
                    frmReceiving.grdItem.ClearSelection()
                    frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows(0).Selected = True
                    frmReceiving.grdItem.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i
                    lblMsg.Text = txtQty.Value & " item/s added."
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.SeaGreen
                    txtBarcode.SelectAll()
                    chk = Item_Chk(0, barcode)
                    If chk = True Then
                        lblDesc.Text = Item_Get(9, barcode)
                    Else
                        lblDesc.Text = Item_Get(13, barcode)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim qty As Integer = 0
            Dim wh As Integer = 0
            Dim sa As Integer = 0
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In frmReceiving.grdItem.Rows
                qty += row.Cells(5).Value
                Dim chkwh As Boolean = Item_Chk(1, row.Cells(1).Value.ToString)
                If chkwh = True Then
                    wh += 1
                End If
                Dim chksa As Boolean = Item_Chk(0, row.Cells(1).Value.ToString)
                If chksa = True Then
                    sa += 1
                End If
            Next
            frmReceiving.lblTotal.Text = "Total Qty: " & qty
            frmReceiving.lblCount.Text = "WH: " & wh & " / SA: " & sa
        End If
        timeScan.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

the code is working. but is there any possible way to scan a datagridview with a gun scanner faster ? the issue is when the datagridview contains a large amount of data (for example 50 items) the scanning takes longer. here is the code.

any help is appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: What is a "gun scanner" and how is it used to scan DGV contents?  One fast way is to act on the data, not the control.  I suspect `Item_Get` is a DB look up?  If so that will slow it down. Not using `Option Strict` is suboptimal.  BTW 50 items is not a large amount of data

Comment: yes you're right about item_get @Plutonix . but is there any way to process this fast ? i mean like. timeinterval or doublebuffered ?

Comment: In **addition** to the things I already mentioned, *design* it to be fast - if you know you need to look things up, fill a datatable with the essentials so you dont have to hit the DB.